# TypeError: Cannot read property 'compile' of undefined

Tags: javascript, compilation, ethereum, solidity

I'm currently trying to follow this tutorial for Ethereum Solidity coding, and for the following code:

```
const path = require('path');
const fs =  require('fs');        // File system module
const solc = require('solc').default;    // Solidity Compiler module

// Note that phrase resolving a link means to substitute the actual location in the file system for the symbolic link
// If we assume that logFile is a symbolic link to dir/logs/HomeLogFile, then resolving it yields dir/logs/HomeLogFile

// Generates a path that points directly to the inbox file. __dirname will be the root direction
// inboxPath = desktop/inbox/contracts/inbox.sol
const inboxPath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'contracts', 'inbox.sol');

// The next step is to actually read the contents of the source file now
// utf8 is the encoding to read the file's content
const source = fs.readFileSync(inboxPath, 'utf8');

// Call solc.compile and pass in our source code, with only 1 contract 
// console.log() means put the output in the console
console.log(solc.compile(source, 1));
```

I get the following error when I hover over `const solc = require('solc').default`:

```
Could not find a declaration file for module 'solc'. 'c:/Users/Hana PC/Desktop/inbox/node_modules/solc/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  Try `npm i --save-dev @types/solc` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'solc';`ts(7016)
```

When I try `node compile.js`, I get:

```
C:\Users\Hana PC\Desktop\inbox\compile.js:18
console.log(solc.compile(source, 1));
                 ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'compile' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Hana PC\Desktop\inbox\compile.js:18:18)
[90m    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)[39m
[90m    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)[39m
[90m    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)[39m
[90m    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)[39m
[90m    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)[39m
[90m    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47[39m
```

I've never used/interacted with TypeScript or JavaScript or anything of the sorts, so I honestly don't even know what this error means. I've already tried uninstalling and reinstalling solc multiple times, all to no avail.

My node.js version is:

```
6.14.8
```

I tried doing some searching online for what the `implicitly has an 'any' type.` means or how it could be fixed, but I honestly didn't get any of it. If it helps, my `package.json` looks like this:

```
{

"name": "inbox",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "compile.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "solc": "^0.8.0"
  }
}
```

Any help is appreciated!

**** Update:**

Tried it with uninstall solc and a fresh install (without using version 0.4.17), and got an Assertion Error:

```
assert.js:383
    throw err;
    ^

AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Invalid callback object specified.
    at runWithCallbacks (C:\Users\Hana PC\Desktop\inbox\node_modules\[4msolc[24m\wrapper.js:97:7)
    at compileStandard (C:\Users\Hana PC\Desktop\inbox\node_modules\[4msolc[24m\wrapper.js:207:14)
    at Object.compileStandardWrapper [as compile] (C:\Users\Hana PC\Desktop\inbox\node_modules\[4msolc[24m\wrapper.js:214:14)
```

Wish I knew what was goin on

Comment: You should check the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/solc/v/0.6.12)

Comment: Thing is, I did see that, I just didn't understand anything, so I was hoping someone could help somehow.

Comment: Your npm install you have used version `0.4.17`, but your package.json says `"solc": "^0.8.0"`. It's possible the older version does not have the `compile` function. Maybe run `npm uninstall solc` and the just do a full `npm install` on your project to get all non-installed packages.

Comment: Did that! Now I got an AssertionError: assert.js:383
    throw err;
    ^

AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Invalid callback object specified.
    at runWithCallbacks (C:\Users\Hana PC\Desktop\inbox\node_modules\[4msolc[24m\wrapper.js:97:7)
    at compileStandard (C:\Users\Hana PC\Desktop\inbox\node_modules\[4msolc[24m\wrapper.js:207:14)
    at Object.compileStandardWrapper [as compile] (C:\Users\Hana PC\Desktop\inbox\node_modules\[4msolc[24m\wrapper.js:214:14)

Comment: Switch back to v0.8.0 and change the import on line #3 to`const solc = require('solc');`


I could get [Example usage without the import callback](https://www.npmjs.com/package/solc#user-content-example-usage-without-the-import-callback) running without any issue but I am not so sure about the `.sol` files so you are on your own on that.

Comment: I see. If it's fine asking, do you think the issue is then in my .sol file?

Comment: I am not sure.. Could you provide me a valid sol file for me to try? Maybe from a tutorial site or the official guides or hosted somewhere on github. I am sorry but I am out of my comfort zone here and don't know anything about sol files to determine it's validity.

Comment: Here: pragma solidity ^0.4.17;

contract inbox
{
    string public message;
    
    function inbox(string initialMessage) public
    {
        message = initialMessage;   
    }
    
    function setMessage(string newMessage) public
    {
        message = newMessage;
    }
}

Comment: Since this solidity file is using v0.4.17, I had to switch the npm package version back to v0.4.17 instead of v0.8.0.
And then it just worked with your js code only.. just remember to remove the `.default` on line #3.

Comment: It worked?? I tried it again, it didnt work :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227504/discussion-between-rahulpsd18-and-hana-ali).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the discussion we had above, since the solidity file is using `v0.4.17`, you should use the same version of `solc` library in your code.

I have created a working example of your code [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/node-js-forked-h1rr1?file=/src/index.js) and the only two changes required were:

- Making sure I use `v0.4.17` of solc.
- Import `const solc = require("solc");` and **not** `const solc = require("solc").default;`

If you are having trouble downgrading the `solc` package, then

1. Delete `package-lock.json` file and `node_modules/` folder.
2. Update the `package.json` files dependency to `"solc": "0.4.17"` and **not** to `"^0.4.17"`
3. Simply run `npm install` one last time.

This should be enough to get you up and running.